# Problem with PIC I2C interface while communicating with SSD1306

Tags: microcontroller, pic, i2c, microchip, oled

My goal is to communicate with SSD1306 controller of OLED 128x32 display with PIC16F15323 which has I2C interface built-in. Obviously, I've read whole documentation for my MCU and for SSD1306 controller and have followed what's needed. But for some reason my PIC has started to initiate resets after each "__delay_ms()" function. I will leave link to GitHub repository here for you to read what I've wrote.

My main question is - why does MCU reset?

GitHub repository: https://github.com/VestnikAUE/OLED-Display-I2C-PIC16F15323.git

P.S. In the code you will find additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you know *exactly* what you're doing, and for some insane reason you need *very exotic* behavior (which ***you*** don't), you should *never* return the main function on an embedded controller.

In other words: **don't ever return the main function** in embedded C.

Add a `while (1) {}` on the line before `return;`. That's usually the place where your application runs from the main context (as opposed to the interrupt context).

```c
void main(void)
{
    // low level / peripheral inits
    
    // application inits
    
    beginTransmission(ADDR);
    
    sendControlByte(0x40);
    
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        sendCommand(0x01);
    
    endTransmission();
    
    // !!! add missing while-forever loop !!!
    while (1)
    {
        // application code
    }

    return;
}
```

Your code executes and then returns from main, which can cause behavior you don't expect.

Relevant question: [Who receives the value returned by main()?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55767/who-receives-the-value-returned-by-main)

---

I'm adding the relevant part of the original code for reference, since the external source can change or be removed at any time:

```c
#include "CONFIG.h"

// I have to mention that I run MCU from 5V pins from Arduino Uno. Pins SDA and SCL of display are pulled-up.
void main(void)
{
    // I have two LEDs on pins RC3 and RC4 to check if MCU works.
    TRISC = 0b000000;
    PORTC = 0b011000;
    __delay_ms(1000);
    PORTC = 0b000000;
    
    // Searching through Internet I found some causes to resets - PO and TO bits.
    // Here I am checking them. Also they are negated, so LEDs must light up.
    if (__timeout && __powerdown) PORTC = 0b011000;
    else if (__timeout && !__powerdown) PORTC = 0b010000;
    else if (!__timeout && __powerdown) PORTC = 0b001000;
    __delay_ms(2000);
    // I suppose PIC resets here 'cause LEDs blink with those periods.
    PORTC = 0b000000;
    
    i2cBegin();
    
    setupI2C();
    
    beginTransmission(ADDR);
    
    sendControlByte(0x00);
    
    sendCommand(0x26);
    sendCommand(0x00);
    sendCommand(0x05);
    sendCommand(0x00);
    sendCommand(0x07);
    sendCommand(0x2F);
    
    endTransmission();
    
    beginTransmission(ADDR);
    
    sendControlByte(0x40);
    
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        sendCommand(0x01);
    
    endTransmission();
    
    // Test: blinking LEDs program
    /*
    
    TRISCbits.TRISC0 = 0;
    TRISCbits.TRISC1 = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        PORTC = 0b000001;
        __delay_ms(2000);
        PORTC = 0b000010;
        __delay_ms(2000);
    }
    */
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My PIC finally stopped resetting!

Comment: Interesting to know how this PIC controller behaves. The TI controllers I've used in the past will end up in an endless loop. Not that it's really relevant, b/c this behavior shouldn't be triggered anyways.