# off-(on) switch with click sound?

Tags: switches

I'm wondering about the industry conventions for switches. I'm looking for a off-(on) switch that makes a click sound and "locks" the button until you release it. There are a lot of switches out there so I want to get the right one from the beginning.

Comment: Do you want a rocker switch or push button switch? Single piece or with separate knob? Panel mounted or PCB mounted?

Comment: push button switch with panel mount. I'm going to put my own 3d printed knob on it.

Comment: Push button switches without knob are mostly PCB mounted. A nice panel mounted type was used on AT PSUs, but unforunately it does not seem to have any contemporary equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

DPDT switches, i.e, toggle switches. The rocker type make clicker noises and look nice if that's what's you're going for. They stay on the setting you just put it on unlike momentary(pushbuttons) switches.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a push button, a tactile switch but for panel mount, sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Do you want it to be programmed in or just the switch?

Comment: Just the switch, off-(on)

Comment: I don't think what you want exists. Momentary switches work by pushing the connection downward and thus completing the circuit. Toggle switches simply hold this position versus reverting back to the default off position. You could easily accomplish this with code by having 1 circuit reading the switch and another doing whatever it is you want, but I don't think this is possible with a button alone.This question might explain how to build one: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30427/using-a-momentary-push-button-as-a-latching-on-off-toggle-switch

Comment: "Toggle switches simply hold this position versus reverting back to the default off position." - That's what I'm looking for, but I want the motion and click sound when you completely have pressed down the push button.

Comment: Then you're going to want to go with a rocker switch. They produce a fairly audible sound that resembles that of a push button momentary switch.

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants the type of pushbutton switch where you push it once and a mechanical latch holds it closed until you push it again to open it.  The mechanical latch makes a very characteristic click.  I'm not sure of the right word for this, maybe "latching pushbutton"?

Comment: I think maybe it's an "on off pushbutton".  There also seems to be something called an "(on) off pushbutton"; I am not sure what the difference is, but it might have to do with whether the button stays physically depressed while the switch is closed.

Comment: Sounds like a "push-On/push-Off" switch, also called "alternate action", I think.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of switches like this.  Often called just what they do "On/Off Latching" switch. see:

[image]

Available from alibaba, ebay, and many others others.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/252102075002?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=82

http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/7-7mm-3Pin-Push-Tactile-Power_1880705912.html

**Round panel mount:**
http://www.adafruit.com/products/1442?gclid=COe72LKgg8kCFdgWgQodnTAApA

**Square panel mount:**
http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/151078944698?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=82

The switches are not normally spec'd for the sound they make, though if you can find one with a higher force value (a stronger spring) it would likely make a loader sound when pressed.